# Postgresql race conditions

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which stores geo position of user. Which looks like this:

```
|id|coords|create_time|
```

And i have controller which saves record in database, but user can save record only once per 5 hours. Simple "if" check is not working, cause if you send a request within like 10ms lets say 100 times, check is going to fail, because record not in db (saving takes some time). So there is simple race condition. How to solve this problem on database level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level throughout.

Then your transactions could be as simple as:

```
START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable
WHERE create_time > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '5 hours';
-- throw an error of the result is not 0
INSERT INTO mytable (oords, create_time) VALUES (..., current_timestamp);
COMMIT;
```

`SERIALIZABLE` isolation will guarantee a serialization error in one of two concurrent transactions like that.

Now `SERIALIZABLE` is simple to use, but it saps performance somewhat, needs a bigger lock table and you have to be ready to repeat transactions that receive a serialization error.

A second solution that works with the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level would be an exclusion constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (
   tstzrange(create_time, create_time + INTERVAL '5 hours') WITH &&
);
```

Here `&&` is the range “overlaps” operator, and the condition would exclude any two entries in the table which are closer than 5 hour.
`tstzrange` is a “`timestamp with time zone`-range” and is the appropriate type if `create_time` is of that type; for `timestamp without time zone` use `tsrange`.

This is automatically safe from race conditions, and one of two concurrent `INSERT`s would receive a constraint violation error.

If you need to have that overlap check per person, let's assume that there is a `person_id` column as well. Then you need to extend the exclusion constraint:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;  -- for GiST indexes on bigint columns
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (
   person_id WITH =,
   tstzrange(create_time, create_time + INTERVAL '5 hours') WITH &&
);
```

Comment: If i try to use last example, i get "functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE". What am i doing wrong?
If i omit CREATE EXTENSION, i get - data type integer has no default operator class for access method "gist"

Comment: nvm fixed with tsrange instead of tstzrange (because im using timestamp without timezone)

Comment: Yes, sorry, for `timestamp without time zone` you need a `tsrange`. I'll mention that in my answer.